# How to deploy React app without shell access?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I've just created a Reactjs App and I want it to work on a website, but the web hosting service I use only gives me FTP access, not shell. Is there a way I could deploy the app anyway?

Comment: You can run the build command and copy the content of the build folder to your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to run build command to build your ReactJS App into html, js and css file then upload these files to your FTP server.